# Arduino Project - Social distance detector

Tags: sensors

I am trying to make a social distance detector for a project of mine. There are many projects online about this, but none of them are the right ones. I'm trying to make a thing that attaches to a lanyard. My original plan was when a PIR sensor detected a human, it would trigger the ultrasonic sensor into measuring the distance between the lanyard and the human. The problem is, the PIR sensor was always displaying "high", and after doing some research, a PIR sensor can be only stationary. I am wondering if there are other easy and cheap options other than PIR sensors that can detect humans accurately? Thanks!

Comment: how does `attaches to a lanyard` make it different from the other projects on the web? ... right now it reads like `I'm buiding a race car, but mine will be green`

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. The lanyard will be hung around a neck, which is not the same as being a "stationary" human detector that will be attached to a wall.

Comment: A normal PIR sensor reacts to movement. It does nit measure distance. Thus it is not interessting for your project. There are other real IR distance sensors. Sensors don't have to be stationary. They will work as long as the involved speed is significantly slower than the sensor. That should be true for IR and ultrasonic sensors for mounting on a human. More important is the direction. When carried around the neck, you need to keep your sensor front facing.

Comment: If a PIR sensor doesn't work, what other options I can do to distinguish between humans and objects?